# How to prevent windows WriteConsole() from using wide chars by default

Tags: c, windows, console-application

I noticed that the WriteConsole() function call only accepts wide characters as input (or else question mark characters are printed).

```
WriteConsole(outputHandle, L"A Message", 268, NULL, NULL);
```

I know that SetConsoleCP() can be called to change the character encoding mode used, but ASCII seems like too much of a special character set to have to be set through this function call. Is there a better way to change the character set in a Windows console application?

Comment: Modern console programs should use Unicode (i.e. `WriteConsoleW`, not `WriteConsoleA`). The CMD shell has used Unicode since 1993, because it was always an NT application and didn't have to worry about being compatible with DOS-based Windows 9x. In the past, most console apps have used legacy codepages, which allowed running them on both DOS-based and NT-based Windows systems. `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP` are for setting the console's input and output codepages for these legacy applications. The default is the system OEM codepage (e.g. 437 in the U.S., 850 in Western Europe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. My compiler (Visual Studio) was set to using Unicode by default (in Project-> ProjectName Properties-> Configuration Properties-> General), so I changed that setting to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". The compiler was basically setting the WriteConsole() macro to WriteConsoleW() (which is for wide characters) instead of WriteConsoleA().